# .apk files give errors on Eclipse when imported

Tags: java, android, eclipse, mobile

I have the code for an Android app and I want to make some small changes and rebuild the .apk file. the changes are small and mostly find replace but when I import the code to my Eclipse I see a lot of errors which most likely is due to library dependencies etc.

I just need some one to set up the code on my Eclipse. Then I can make the changes and recompile the new apk.
[image]

Comment: I think you have to add support libs.

Comment: How to do that "add support libs "